# Fragment adapter incompatible type

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
package com.androidnik.tourguide;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.androidnik.tourguide.AmusmentsFragment;
import com.androidnik.tourguide.HotelRestaurantsFragment;
import com.androidnik.tourguide.MustVisitFragment;
import com.androidnik.tourguide.ToDoList;
import com.androidnik.tourguide.ToDoListFragment;

private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Numbers", "Family", "Color", "Phrases" };

public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return new MustVisitFragment();
    } else if (position == 1){
        return new ToDoListFragment();
    } else if(position == 2){
        return new HotelRestaurantsFragment();
    }
    else
        return new AmusmentsFragment();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabTitles[position];
}
}
```

required android.support.v4.app.fragment what i do of this error.
 In the actvity of each fragment i cant use getSupportFragmentManager instead i have to use getFragmentManager becuase the former method wont get the fragment object as parameter while performing the .add() function via fragment transaction

This works

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MustVisitFragment()).commit();
```

This doesnt

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MustVisitFragment()).commit();
```

so i have no choice other than to use v7 fragment manager but that is not accepted by my fragment adapter

Answer (score 0):

`MustVisitFragment.java`

Has this import

```
android.app.Fragment;
```

Instead of this

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```